# Parameter 1 of method batchConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchConfigurerConfiguration$JdbcBatchConfiguration required

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch and using @Scheduler annotation to scheduled a job at some frequency.

From the error message it looks like Spring Boot expecting atleast Spring DataSource related entry but I dont need it, because I am not dealing with the DB as of now.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method batchConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchConfigurerConfiguration$JdbcBatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

**application.properties**

```
cron.job.expression=*/1 * * * *
```

Other class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Primary
public class ScheduledDomainJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job scheduledJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("scheduledJob").flow(step1()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Domain, Domain>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader()).writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Domain> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Domain> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("csv/domain-1-03-2017.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Domain>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[]{"id", "domain"});
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Domain>() {{
                setTargetType(Domain.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomWriter writer() {
        CustomWriter writer = new CustomWriter();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public RunScheduler scheduler() {
        RunScheduler scheduler = new RunScheduler();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

**CustomerWriter.java**

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<Domain> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Domain> items) throws Exception {
        log.info("writer ....... " + items.size());
        for (Domain domain : items) {
            log.info(domain + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are using spring boot version 2. You can make some changes in the code like below.

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Primary
public class ScheduledDomainJob extends DefaultBatchConfigurer
```

Define the following annotation on you spring-boot application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

You can find the more details on [Spring Batch Hello world example using Spring boot](http://walkingtechie.blogspot.com/2017/03/spring-batch-hello-world-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Define the following annotation on you springboot initialization class.

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

If that does not work, try to add the H2 or hsqldb to the maven dependencies.

Comment: Right Thanks. I am getting another error now, why we need to exclude that ?